# how to split the give string in expected output

Tags: javascript, node.js

/*  How to split the string and store to two variable only name and email id.*/

```
  var str = "chris <chris.fc@email.in>"
  
  /*expected output`enter code here`
  name     = "chris"
  email_id = "chris.fc@email.in" */
```

Must remove the space and the ( "<>" )return the only string.

Comment: You aren't splitting, you're matching. `const match = str.match(/(.*)\s*<(.*)>/);` then `match[1]` and `match[2]` are your name and email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would split the input on the single space occurring after the name and before the email address.  Then, take a substring to isolate the email address.

```js
var str = "chris <chris.fc@email.in>";
var parts = str.split(/[ ](?=<)/);
var name = parts[0];
var email = parts[1].substring(1, parts[1].length - 1);
console.log("name     = " + name);
console.log("email_id = " + email);
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use regular expression to remove unwanted characters inside a string and assign it to two different variables as below

```
var str = "chris <chris.fc@email.in>"
const [name,email] = str.split(/<|>/g);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split()` the string, replace unwanted values from your string using `replace()`

```js
var str = "chris <chris.fc@email.in>"
var splitedarr=str.split('<');
var name =splitedarr[0];
console.log("name :" + name)
var emailid =splitedarr[1].replace('>','')
console.log("email_id :" +emailid)
```